# How does an endoscope form the image?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, fiber-optics

I am trying to do ray tracing for an endoscope, but I don't see how it could form a sharp image that could be viewed at the eyepiece.

In the diagram the box in the middle is the "fiber", but the light from the object (the dot on the left) comes out of the fiber as if they originate from two locations (top and bottom), and if viewed through the eyepiece at the end, wouldn't two images form (the two dots on the right)?

Also, if just looking at the image end of the fiber by eye directly without eyepiece, one should still see the image of the object, right? I don't see how it would work with ray tracing in this case either. And should the image in this case be inverted or upright, or left/right flipped, or does it depend?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Optical fibres can be accurately aligned in an array such that the order of the fibres at one end is identical to the order in the other end to form what is called a coherent bundle. If an image is projected at one end of a bundle, each individual fibre transmits the light impinging on it, and the ordered array of optical fibres will transmit an image to the other end.

[image]

An important thing to note is that the individual fibers used in a bundle are contained (clad) in a opaque covering so that light from one fibre does not go into an adjacent fibre.

Comment: I don't have any experience with endoscope fiber bundles, but this is similar to the light sources used with high-power microscopes. A really bright light sits in a case on the bench and a fiber bundle passes the light to a ring around the microscope lens. One big difference is that the fibers aren't arranged to be the same  on both ends. I suspect that they are arranged to *not* be the same, to even out differences in brightness.

Comment: @Farcher, so let's pretend in my diagram the fiber is the "central one" in the bundle and the object "circle" is focused on one end of the fiber by the lens. Now how does the light from the object produce an image on the other end of the fiber? What's the mistake in my ray tracing diagram because clearly the two beams entering upward and downward into the fiber do not converge at the other end of the fiber to form an image.

Comment: @Cosmo, the image doesn't pass through just one fiber. The image is projected on the input face of the bundle. Each fiber carries a different "pixel" of the image to the other end of the fiber bundle. Then the output lens relays an image of the output face of the bundle to .... whatever it is designed to send the image to.

Comment: @Cosmo Each fiber transmits one "pixel" from the input plane to the output plane. Within each pixel, the rays are scrambled, but since the input pixels map 1:1 to the output pixels, the output plane reproduces an image focused on the input plane at pixel resolution.

Comment: "Fibres within the bundle are often $<8\mu \rm m$ in diameter and can be several metres long. Some endoscopes may contain $30000$ individual fibres in each bundle and it is currently possible to fit $50000-70000$ fibres in a $1\,\rm m$ diameter bundle." Each fibre is a pixel.

Comment: @JohnDoty , "Within each pixel, the rays are scrambled, but since the input pixels map 1:1 to the output pixels", this did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The objective lens forms an image of the object on the end of the fiber bundle.

The fiber bundle is a bundle of very fine parallel fibers. Each fiber carries a pixel to the other end of the fiber bundle. What comes out of the fiber bundle looks just like what goes in.

The eyepiece send the image at the other end of the fiber bundle to your eye or a camera.